# Loading Landsat 8 tiles into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, landsat

I have 65 Landsat 8 tiles I download off of EarthViewer form the USGS website. What is the fastest way I can load these files into QGIS?

My issue is that each tile I downloaded came with a folder where every spectral band is separate tiff file instead of all being in a single GeoTIFF.

Is there a fast way to load the files and get an RGB image or am I stuck making virtual rasters/ combining the bands for each file?

Comment: If you wish to ask the same question for ArcGIS Desktop please do that in another question.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the dataset you are working on?